# API return writeable

Tags: scala, concurrency, playframework

I'm trying to convert a few endpoints I have to use concurrency.  I have the following method for the controller:

Original method

```
def getHistory(id:String) = Action {
  val response = historyService.getPersonHistory(id)

  Ok(write(response)) as "application/json"
}
```

New Method

```
def getHistory(id:String) = Action.async {
    val response = scala.concurrent.Future {
        historyService.getPersonHistory(id)
    }

   response.map(i => Ok(i))
```

}

So, when we try this with a simple example process (not calling another method, but just calculating an Int) it seems to work.  In the new version above, I keep getting the error:

```
"No implicits found for parameter writable: Writeable[historyResponse]
```

Cannot write an instance of `models.HistoryResponse` to HTTP response. Try to define a `Writeable[models.HistoryResponse]`"

I'm new to Scala, and having difficulty finding information on making writeables.  What do I need to be able to return the results as before?

Thanks

Comment: What is the signature of `historyService.getPersonHistory`? Where is the method `write` in `Ok(write(response)) as "application/json"` declared? Try to look for implicits in this area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define an `implicit val tjs: Writes[HistoryResponse]` or even better, `implicit val format: Format[HistoryResponse] = Json.format[HistoryResponse]` in the companion object for `HistoryResponse`, so that play can auto convert your data to json. by the way, not a good name for `i` in the map function, something like "history" would be better instead of "i".

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "companion object"  that my model itself needs to change?

Comment: @Limey You can find more [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/companion-objects.html), you can also use other ways of injecting the `Writable` , but using companion object is the best practice.

Comment: wrapping the result in a write (Ok(write(result)) as "application/json") solved the problem.  Thanks!